# Xcode Returning (lldb), while running C application

Tags: c, xcode, macos, osx-yosemite, lldb

I'm trying to run the following code on C, using Xcode, and it's returning an erro that I can't figure out, any clue on it? Below is the code and a print of the Xcode Screen.

It runs mostly the code, until I select the number of duplicate entries it should remove.

[image: Error Returned]

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
int combinacoes(int n, int r);
void filtro_75_5();
void filtro_60_6();
void filtro_49_7();
void filtro_60_8();
void filtro_60_9();
void filtro_geral();

int** Filtro;
int npainel;
int ndezenas;
int* dezenas;
int** Base = 0;
bool verificaRepeticoes = true;
int total_registros;
int repeticao = 0;
int total_registros_r = 0;
FILE *f;


int main()
{

    printf("Digite o Painel: ");
    scanf("%d",&npainel);

    printf("Digite a Dezena: ");
    scanf("%d",&ndezenas);

    int resultado;
    resultado = combinacoes(npainel,ndezenas);
    printf("%d",resultado);

    int iniciar;
    printf("\nDeseja gerar as combinacoes [1] Sim [2] Nao");
    scanf("%d", &iniciar);

    int usaragrupamento;
    printf("\nUsar agrupamento de Dezenas [1] Sim [2] Nao]");
    scanf("%d", &usaragrupamento);

    int filt_repeticoes;
    printf("\nUsar filtro de Qtd de repeticoes no Total de:");
    scanf("%d", &filt_repeticoes);

    if (iniciar ==1)
    {

        f = fopen( "/Volumes/BANCO/combinacoes.txt" , "w" );


        int rows = 2;
        int cols = 5;

        int** Filtro = calloc(rows, sizeof *Filtro); // I prefer calloc unless i really am reallocating

        for (int i = 0 ; i < rows ; ++i)
        {
            Filtro[i] = calloc(cols, sizeof **Filtro);
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < rows ; ++i)
        {
            free(Filtro[i]);
        }
        free(Filtro);

        /*redim dezenas(ndezenas-1) //Vetor de cada dezena do conjunto*/
        dezenas = (int *)realloc(dezenas, (ndezenas-1) * sizeof(int *));

        /*redim Base(-1,-1)*/
        Base = (int **) realloc(Base,(-1) * sizeof(*Base));

        /*redim Base(1000,ndezenas-1)*/
        Base = (int **) realloc(Base,(1000) * sizeof(*Base));

        if (usaragrupamento == 1)
        {

            switch(ndezenas){

                case 5:
                    filtro_75_5();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    filtro_60_6();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    filtro_49_7();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    filtro_60_8();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    filtro_60_9();
                    break;

            }
        }else{

            filtro_geral();
        }


    }

    return 0;
}

int combinacoes(int n, int r)
{
    int combinacao;

    //combinacao = 0;
    if (n<1 || r <1)
    {

        combinacao = 0;
    }else{

        double u;
        double v;
        int w;
        int t;

        u=1;
        t=1;

        //for(t=1;u=u*t;
        while(t<=n)
        {
            u=u*t;
            t++;
        }
        //calcula o fatorial de n(!n)
        v= 1;
        t= 1;
        if(n>r)
        {
            while(t<=n-r)
            {
                v = v*t;
                t++;
            }
        }
        w = 1;
        t = 1;

        //Calcula Fatorial de n-r (n-r)!
        while(t<=r)
        {
            w=w*t;
            t++;
        }

        combinacao = round(u/(v*w));
        return combinacao;
    }

    return combinacao;
}

void filtro_49_7()
{

    Filtro[0][0]=1;
    Filtro[0][1]=7;

    Filtro[1][0]=8;
    Filtro[1][1]=14;

    Filtro[2][0]=15;
    Filtro[2][1]=21;

    Filtro[3][0]=22;
    Filtro[3][1]=28;

    Filtro[4][0]=29;
    Filtro[4][1]=35;

    Filtro[5][0]=36;
    Filtro[5][1]=42;

    Filtro[6][0]=43;
    Filtro[6][1]=49;

}

void filtro_60_6(){

    Filtro[0][0]=1;
    Filtro[0][1]=30;

    Filtro[1][0]=1;
    Filtro[1][1]=30;

    Filtro[2][0]=1;
    Filtro[2][1]=30;

    Filtro[3][0]=31;
    Filtro[3][1]=60;

    Filtro[4][0]=31;
    Filtro[4][1]=60;

    Filtro[5][0]=31;
    Filtro[5][1]=60;

}

void filtro_60_8(){
    Filtro[0][0]=1;
    Filtro[0][1]=15;
    Filtro[1][0]=1;
    Filtro[1][1]=15;

    Filtro[2][0]=16;
    Filtro[2][1]=30;
    Filtro[3][0]=16;
    Filtro[3][1]=30;

    Filtro[4][0]=31;
    Filtro[4][1]=45;
    Filtro[5][0]=31;
    Filtro[5][1]=45;

    Filtro[6][0]=46;
    Filtro[6][1]=60;
    Filtro[7][0]=46;
    Filtro[7][1]=60;
}

void filtro_60_9(){
    Filtro[0][0]=1;
    Filtro[0][1]=20;

    Filtro[1][0]=1;
    Filtro[1][1]=20;

    Filtro[2][0]=1;
    Filtro[2][1]=20;

    Filtro[3][0]=21;
    Filtro[3][1]=40;

    Filtro[4][0]=21;
    Filtro[4][1]=40;

    Filtro[5][0]=21;
    Filtro[5][1]=40;

    Filtro[6][0]=41;
    Filtro[6][1]=60;

    Filtro[7][0]=41;
    Filtro[7][1]=60;

    Filtro[8][0]=41;
    Filtro[8][1]=60;
}

void filtro_75_5(){

    Filtro[0][0]=1;
    Filtro[0][1]=15;
    Filtro[1][0]=16;
    Filtro[1][1]=30;
    Filtro[2][0]=31;
    Filtro[2][1]=45;
    Filtro[3][0]=46;
    Filtro[3][1]=60;
    Filtro[4][0]=61;
    Filtro[4][1]=75;
}

void filtro_geral()
{
    int x;
    int n;
    int r;

    r=ndezenas;
    n=npainel;
        x=1;

        while(x<=r-1)
        {
            Filtro[x][0]=1;
            Filtro[x][1]=n;
            x++;
        }

}

void gerar_dezenas(int npainel, int ndezenas, int inicio,int termino, int nivel)
{

    int w,unidade, xx,igual;
    char *sszero = NULL;//, sgeral[1];
    char *sgeral = NULL;
    bool duplicou = false;

    unidade = inicio;

    while(unidade<=termino+nivel)
    {

        if (unidade>=Filtro[nivel-1][0] && unidade<=Filtro[nivel-1][1])
        {
            dezenas[nivel-1] = unidade;

            if (nivel<ndezenas)
            {
                gerar_dezenas(npainel,ndezenas,unidade+1,npainel-ndezenas,nivel+1);
            }else{
                sgeral = (char *)realloc(sgeral, 1 * sizeof(char *));
                //sgeral[0] = '';
                duplicou=false;

                //xojo
                if (verificaRepeticoes ==true){
                    xx = total_registros-1;

                    while(xx>=1)
                    {
                        igual =0;

                        w=0;

                        while(w<ndezenas-1)
                        {
                            if(Base[xx][w] == dezenas[w])
                            {
                                igual=igual+1;
                            }
                            w++;
                        }

                        if (igual>(ndezenas-repeticao))
                        {
                            duplicou = true;
                            return;
                        }

                        xx--;
                    }
                }

                //////Adiciona um conjunto a Base
                if (duplicou==false || total_registros==0){

                    w = 0;

                    while (w < ndezenas-1){

                        if (dezenas[w]<10){
                            sszero = (char *)realloc(sszero, 2 * sizeof(char *));
                            sszero[0]='0';
                        }
                        /*else{
                         sszero = (char *)realloc(sszero, 1 * sizeof(char *));
                         sszero[0]="";
                         }*/

                        /////So alimenta vetor se for para verificar repeticoes
                        if (verificaRepeticoes==true){
                            Base[total_registros][w]=dezenas[w];
                        }

                        int tam_sgeral = sizeof(sgeral);
                        sgeral = (char *)realloc(sgeral, (sizeof(sgeral) + sizeof(sszero) + sizeof(dezenas[w]))* sizeof(char *));

                        int z;
                        z=0;

                        while(z<sizeof(sszero))
                        {
                            sgeral[tam_sgeral+z] = sszero[z];
                        }

                        tam_sgeral = tam_sgeral + z;
                        z=0;

                        char str[2];
                        sprintf(str, "%d", dezenas[w]);
                        while(z<sizeof(dezenas[w]))
                        {
                            sgeral[tam_sgeral+z] = str[z];
                            //strcpy(sgeral[tam_sgeral+z],str[z]);
                        }

                        w++;
                    }

                    total_registros=total_registros+1;
                    //int** Base2;
                    if (total_registros % 1000 == 0)
                    {
                        Base = (int **) realloc(Base,(total_registros+1000) * sizeof(*Base)); //Vetor total com os conjuntos de combinacoes
                        /*TfGerados.text=str(total_registros);
                         TfGerados.refresh;*/
                        printf("%s",&"Gerados: " [ total_registros]);
                    }

                    if (f != NULL)
                    {
                        printf("Teste");
                        fwrite(sgeral , 1 , sizeof(sgeral) , f);

                    }
                }
                else{

                    total_registros_r=total_registros_r+1;

                    if (total_registros_r % 10000 == 0){
                        printf("%s", &"Jogados Fora: " [ total_registros_r]);
                        /*TfJogadosFora.text=str(total_registros_r);
                         TfJogadosFora.refresh*/
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        else{

            total_registros_r=total_registros_r+1;

            if (total_registros_r % 10000 == 0){
                printf("%s", &"Jogados Fora: " [ total_registros_r]);
                /*TfJogadosFora.text=str(total_registros_r)
                 TfJogadosFora.refresh*/
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `Filtro` is not initialised properly.  `Filtro` is a block of pointers to int but after the realloc all of those pointers are dangling.  Once you have allocated some memory to `Filtro` you must loop through for each element in `Filtro` and alloc the space to hold the ints.

This is what you have assuming `ndezenas-1` is 2.

```
Filtro -->+-----+
          | int*|---> ???
          +-----+
          | int*|---> ???
          +-----+
```

This is what you need

```
Filtro -->+-----+     +------------ 
          | int*|---> |int|int|int| .... etc 
          +-----+     +------------
          | int*|-+ 
          +-----+ |   +------------ 
                  +-> |int|int|int| .... etc 
                      +------------
```

Here's an example of how to do it

```
int rows = 2;
int cols = 5;

int** filtro = calloc(rows, sizeof *filtro); // I prefer calloc unless i really am reallocating

for (int i = 0 ; i < rows ; ++i)
{
    filtro[i] = calloc(cols, sizeof **filtro);
}
```

Also to free the memory at the end

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < rows ; ++i)
{
    free(filtro[i]);
}
free(filtro);
```

**Edit**

My example was just an example.  You weren't meant to copy it verbatim.

The big problem now is that you have now declared Filtro twice, once as a global variable and once as a local variable to main.  This means the global version never gets any memory allocated to it. You do not need to redeclare Filtro when you do the calloc.

```
filtro = calloc(rows, sizeof *filtro);
```

The second big problem is that you are freeing the memory straight away.  You don't do that until after you have finished using it.

Comment: Hey @JeremyP, thank you for answering, could you shed some light on how I do it? I'm really a newbie on C, I got what you meant, I just don't know to do it.

Comment: @DiegoPatrocinio see edit (not tested or even compiled, but should work)

Comment: I don't know if I got something wrong, but returned the same error =( [Print Screen Here](http://imgur.com/XmlQ0H2)

Comment: @DiegoPatrocinio You'll need to add your new code to the question.  The debugger says that `Filtro` is still NULL

Comment: Hey @JeremyP once again, thank you for your help! I edited the OP with the actual code.

Comment: I just saw your edit, I'll try it and let you know!is it possible that you could contact me via e-mail? It's on my profile. @JeremyP